# Sitecore and Json serialization - weird conversion

Tags: json, serialization, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

**I have an issues as follows:**

On my local, Azure, + 3 other servers my mapping code looks at latitude and longitude coordinates that are stored in a Sitecore item.

On my new QA and PROD Sitecore servers, that I have not used before as they are sitting on a new hosting provider, I have the following issue:

**If you look at the picture below:**
[image]

**The coordinates are stored correctly but the final output when serialized ot Json is like this:**
[image]

Anyone got any ideas why the decimal point would have been stripped out?

as I said, the code works on many different environments so I am thinking the new hosting provider has set something that is different to my other working environments.

I will keep investigating but thought I would put this out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was this:

Change this:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

to this:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-AU" uiculture="en" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be a Culture issue. Check that the correct culture is set in web.config or on the page.

Tip:
If you want to set the Culture from the Context Sitecore Language, here is how:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Context.ContentLanguage.CultureInfo;
```

Comment: Thanks @thomas. I thought you had saved the day but I have my language set as language="en-AU" already. Remember this is related to .NET to Json serialization. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Are you treating your values numerically, or as strings (there will be at least an implicit string conversion to the JSON output)?